# Powershell string parameter validation

Tags: string, powershell, formatting

I have a powershell script related to SQL Server which requires the user to pass a string only in this format : machineName\instanceName. For eg., MYMACHINE\MYINST. If the argument is not in this format, the script should display the usage syntax. Can someone please provide script. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello new user, this is not a place for people to write scripts for you. You need to try something yourself and if you get stuck, SO will help.

Comment: sorry, it was super urgent. Next time i will try and then ask if i fail. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [parameter validation](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2011/05/15/simplify-your-powershell-script-with-parameter-validation.aspx). Put something like this at the beginning of your script:

```psh
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
  [Parameter()]
  [ValidateScript({
    if ($_ -match '.+\\.+') {
      $true
    } else {
      Write-Host 'Parameter must have the form MACHINE\INSTANCE.'
      $false
    }
  })]
  [string]$Instance
)
```